# Error al ejecutar hola mundo en node

Tags: nodejs

Buenas una consulta sucede que instalé node con instalador en mi pc , pero cuando ejecuto no responde alguna idea ? aquí mi script para que explicarme mejor

```
var http = require('http');

var manejador = function(solicitud, respuesta){
    console.log("Hola mundo");
    respuesta.end();
}

var servidor = http.createServer(manejador);
servidor.listen(8080);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has una prueba colocando node -v, otra  cosa tu problema es cuando ejecutas que comando?

Comment: pensé que saldría "hola mundo"  en la consola , pero no sale , solo se queda parpadeando el cursor  , cuando ejecuto    node -v me arroja la version   v6.11.2

Answer (score 2):

Estás levantando un servidor http con node.js por lo tanto el mensaje "hola mundo" aparecerá cuando accedas a ese servidor.
Como buena práctica te recomiendo agregar lo siguiente a tu código:

```
var http = require('http');

var manejador = function(solicitud, respuesta){
    console.log("Hola mundo");
    respuesta.end();
}

var servidor = http.createServer(manejador);
servidor.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Servidor http corriendo en http://localhost:8080");
});
```

Para probar tu código sigue los siguientes pasos:

1.-Desde cmd ejecuta nuevamente el comando node server.js

2.-En la barra de direcciones de algún navegador (chrome, firefox, opera, etc) ingresa a http://localhost:8080

3.-En cmd aparecerá el mensaje hola mundo

4.-Para detener el servidor presiona ctrl+c

En cuanto al comando node help (si quieres ayuda para comandos de node) teclea node -h

Comment: tenia instalado el xampp pero esta inactivo cuando ejecuto una aplicacion siempre la ejecuto asi    http://localhost/carpeta/scrip.php   sin los 8080 y funciona , hace poco instale laravelhttp://localhost:8080/  sale La conexión ha sido reiniciada , pero si ejecuto http://localhost   me arroja   The connection to 'localhost' failed.
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d).
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión 127.0.0.1:80   alguien puede orientarme ?

Comment: Esto es referente a la pregunta de arriba?

Comment: si debo descartar por que no se ejecuta el hola mundo en mi consola cmd con node  apesar de hacer todo lo indicado

Comment: entonces cambie el puerto del archivo js

Comment: gracias ya salio